# Add custom agenda options instead of replacing the whole set

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, config

I use some custom agendas for work and some for personal stuff. At the moment I load a huge set of custom agendas in `org-agenda-custom-commands` containing all agendas for work and for personal stuff. This clutters up the dispatcher.

When I define two different sets of custom agendas, one for work and one for personal, I can only load and access agendas of one set. But with home office, sometimes I need "work agendas" on my personal computer.

How can I write the configuration, that I can "add" sets of agendas to `org-agenda-custom-commands` if necessary, without completely replacing it with one set or the other?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking: it seems that you want a way to change `org-agenda-custom-commands` to sometimes be the home commands, sometimes be the office commands and sometimes be both and that you have a way to choose which one of the three possibilities will apply at any particular moment. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @NickD Yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is to use a function which sets the variable and then calls the dispatcher. Something like:

```
(defun my/org-agenda-dispatcher-PERSONAL ()
  (interactive)
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("1" "Week Agenda + All Tasks"
           ((agenda "w" ((org-agenda-span 'week)))
            (todo "TODO|LATER"
                  ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(todo-state-up))
                   (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled)))
                  )))))
  (org-agenda))

(defun my/org-agenda-dispatcher-WORK ()
  (interactive)
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("1" "Today's Agenda + Priority Tasks"
           ((agenda "d" ((org-agenda-span 'day)))
            (todo "TODO"
                  ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(todo-state-up))
                   (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled))))))))
  (org-agenda))
```

Then you just call your custom functions rather than the generic `org-agenda` command.

But you'd have to watch out for other commands which might rely on the `org-agenda-custom-commands` variable.